# Diferença entre // e /*...*/

Tags: javascript, string, comentários

Até onde eu entendia, utilizar `//` para comentar uma linha e `/*...*/` era a mesma coisa, com a diferença que o segundo abrangia mais de uma linha caso necessário.

Existe ALGUMA diferença entre fazer

```
 // var a = 'teste'
```

e

```
/* var a = 'teste' */
```

?

Pergunto pois me deparei com um caso estranho, onde comentava código com problema dentro de uma template string (que criava uma tag de script com um código com erro de sintaxe dentro dela) e conforme comentava a linha com problema usando o `/* */` eu não recebia erro de sintaxe, mas quando comentava a mesma linha com `//`, me dava erro de sintaxe ao rodar.

Segue o código onde tive o problema:

```
$('#dadosBeneficiario').html(`
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function dropDown(node) {
            var drop = $(node).next();
            drop.slideToggle('slow');
        }

        function toggleObs(botao) {
            var campo = $(botao).prev();
            if (campo.val() !== '') {
                if($('#descricaoOpcional').val() !== '') {
                    /* $('#descricaoOpcional').val($('#descricaoOpcional').val() + "\n______________________________________________________\n" + campo.val()); */
                    $(botao).hide();
                } else {
                    $('#descricaoOpcional').val($('#descricaoOpcional').val() + campo.val());
                    $(botao).hide();
                }
            } else if ($(botao).val() === "Salvar") {
                return;
            }
            campo.toggle('fast');
            $(botao).val('Salvar');
        }
    </script>`);
```

Ao comentar a linha dessa forma, o código ignorava a linha e rodava.
Mas ao comentar com barra dupla, eu recebia erro de sintaxe:

```
// $('#descricaoOpcional').val($('#descricaoOpcional').val() + "\n______________________________________________________\n" + campo.val());
```

Por que isso ocorria?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do ponto de vista semântico do código, zero, afinal comentário não muda nada nele, é só informação visual para o programador, e que não deve ser abusada como muitos o fazem.

Existe os dois tipos porque eles podem ser vir para motivações diferentes. Alguns dirão que só o segundo realmente é necessário porque ele pode ser usado em todos os lugares que o primeiro pode ser usado. O primeiro é uma facilitador, você indica o início do comentário e o fim será o fim da linha. Mas há um tendência de preferirmos mais o uso do `//` sempre que possível.

O uso do `/* ... */` tem um marcador de início do comentário e do fim, então ele pode conter várias linhas ou pode estar no meio de uma linha.

Ele é muito usado para o que chamamos de *comment out*, ou seja, aquele comentário de código mesmo que tiramos temporariamente para testar algo, para mudar alguma coisa sem perder o que tinha feito antes. O problema é quando a pessoa deixa isso além do tempo de teste, principalmente quando manda para o repositório e torna parte integrante da base de código. Código que não é mais usado deve sempre ser retirado.

O uso em várias linhas só é adequado quando vai explicar algo complexo, de como se chegou naquela fórmula ou coisas do tipo, não é para comentar código ou para colocar informações de autoria, data, e informações que são variáveis em cada momento. Há controvérsias se deveria colocar a licença do código.

O uso no meio de uma linha (for o uso bem temporário) só deve ser para explicar aquele trecho, mas quase sempre que precisa disto deveria quebrar em linhas, e aí o `//` pode ser adequando também.

Já vi uso quando não vai passar um argumento em chamada de função, colocar o que deveria ser passado ali, ou pelo menos indicar que teria um argumento ali.

No exemplo mostrado poderia usar qualquer um deles, dede que usado certo. Como não foi mostrado o uso do `//` não temos como saber o que fez de errado. Veja que não dá erro:

```js
console.log("teste");
// $('#descricaoOpcional').val($('#descricaoOpcional').val() + "\n______________________________________________________\n" + campo.val());
console.log("fim");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Comments.js).

Porém, depois nos comentários foi melhor explicitado que há problema de renderização do jQuery. Quanto menos usar jQUery melhor, ele é lento e traz problemas. Mas como usou teve um deles. O comentário acabou complicado o *parser* dentro da *string* e ele não achou o fim do comentário neste caso.

Comment: Maniero, agradeço as informações, mas ainda não consigo entender o motivo do código ter me dado erro de sintaxe estando comentado com barras duplas. Eu cometi algum erro comentando? O que houve?

Comment: Conforme eu escrevi não temos como saber, você só postou o certo e não o errado.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com a forma que comentei com barra dupla, desculpe.

Comment: Sem contexto, assim é óbvio que não dá erro, dentro de um contexto poderia dar, mas só nele daria para ver o erro. Nem postou o erro, pode nem ser o que está falando.

Comment: Creio que o erro foi por estar dentro da template string, quando tento fora eu não recebo erro. O erro era um erro de sintaxe normal informando que havia um caractere inesperado em uma linha

Comment: Agora que eu vi a enorme gambiarra ali. Nem é um código, é um texto que depois será injetado pelo jQuery. Bom, quase todo o uso de jQuery é errado. Hoje ele é quase desnecessário, e o que as pessoas usam é pra digitar menos, o que por si só já é um erro. tem um jeito fácil e simples de fazer o mesmo e um jeito maluco, esse é o jeito maluco, que pode dar todo tipo de problema. Pra falar a verdade é sorte funciona até sem comentário.

Comment: Eu tive que fazer isso pois essa div do html ignorava código externo por alguma razão que nem os programadores plenos aqui na minha empresa conseguiram explicar. Então tive que injetar o JS dentro da div pra poder executar.

Comment: A solução para consertar uma gambiarra nunca é criar outra.

Comment: O sistema onde eu trabalho tem tanta gambiarra dentro de gambiarra dentro de outra gambiarra desde que eu entrei na empresa que pra arrumar tudo seria mais fácil desenvolver de novo do zero. Enfim, pra finalizar isso, na prática não tem diferença comentar uma linha das duas formas diferentes conforme perguntei no começo, na hora de ler, certo?

Comment: Em condições normais, não.